# asp.net only occasionally calling Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

*Report updated with new information.*

My initial report concerned an asp.net site / app, with vb.net codefiles, that only seems to work properly when debug is set to true in web.config.  When debug=false the search function and the links to create a new search (which simply hyperlinks that reload the page) will occasionally not work, leaving the page partially loaded or not loaded at all.

From further investigation, it appears as though Page_Load is only being occasionally called, as I have a search object defined there that is occasionally found to be null (leading to the problems I've seen) in my button_click event (the first method that I find called when I refresh the page after a search).

Not really sure what to make of this or how to begin solving it. Have not found much of anything that suggests others have had the same problem. Any help appreciated!

I thought it might have been caching. Tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105130/page-load-not-being-called-on-re-navigation) to no avail.  I also discovered the setting of the debug flag is a red herring... having it set to true only masks the problem for a while, whereas setting it to false makes it appear almost immediately.

Comment: Without posting code, its hard to make an accurate diagnosis, but it could be your web app is executing getAttribute across a cross-domain site. Make sure there are no iframes or anything that contains data from another domain.

Comment: I have a button click event handler that is used to generate and display the results of a search.  When I refresh the search results, most of the time, it appears as though the button click is called to operate on a properly set search object.  The search object is constructed in the Page_Load.  When my problem occurs... seemingly at random, it appears as though the Page_Load is not being called.  Does that make sense - that Page_Load would not be called before a button click?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the user running the web page is having administrator rights .If not see whether the issue existing when running as an admin.
2. Try to run from a different browser .

Comment: The user running the page does have admin rights (he is me).  I've tried from IE and Chrome.. no difference.  It simply appears as though, from time to time, the Page_Load is not being run.  I have a couple of lines in there which update fields on the screen, or show an error message... when the error occurs, those text fields are either not shown at all, or are not updated with my "proof of running Page_Load" text.